# Is this mold on my sour dough starter?

Tags: sourdough-starter

[image]I received the starter in early June this year. I feed 2 parts flour to 1 part well water. The flour is sometimes organic whole wheat, sometimes white flour. I keep it in the refrigerator. I feed once a week, but sometimes longer. It had been about two weeks when I opened it and saw stuff that looked like yeast granules. They are tan in color. I fed it and let it sit out for a few hours, then back in frig. I just took a look at the starter and it looks filmy, like the same thing is developing. It has a strong yeasty smell.
Is this mold? Is it still usable?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you add some more details to your post - such as a photo (preferably macro) of the thing you want to show us, and what you have been doing for the starter (e.g. storage conditions, length of culture, flour(s) used etc).

Comment: I received the starter in early June this year. Feed 2 parts flour to 1 part well water. Flour sometimes organic whole wheat sometimes white flour. Starter is kept in frig. Fed once a week but sometimes longer. It had been about two weeks when I opened it and saw the stuff that looked like yeast granules. Tan in color. I fed it and let it sit out for a few hours, then back in frig. Just took a look at the starter and looks filmy like the same thing is developing. Strong yeasty smell.

Comment: Your yeast is growing yeast!  That sounds like a vigorous starter.  I propose you take it out on the road and make some bread.

Comment: On the surface, it sounds like it is doing its job, likely could use mixing a bit more often, but for fears of mold or other contamination a picture is really needed for anyone to guess.  My experience is that sourdough can overcome a lot and stay healthy and active, but if it goes bad you know it and it is not a yeasty smell.  A picture in this case is worth at least 1,000 words though.  ;)

Comment: I don't know how to post a picture. Sorry.

Comment: When you go to edit your post - have a look at the tool bar. There should be a button that looks like some very pointy mountains with a tiny sun in the top right corner. That's the image button. It should be next to some curly braces "{}"

Answer (score 4):

No. You are looking at "hooch", the fermented alcohol released by the yeast organisms, floating on top of the starter with little blobs of starter pushing up from the gas released below. Your starter is just fine.

Pour off the hooch and continue.

Comment: @Martha Hooch is normal part though heavily hooched starter tends to mean you need to feed more or more often.  Pink or dark brown tend to be danger signs.  No sign of that in yours.